# Find optimal set of substrings in given string

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, substring, mathematical-optimization

**I'm trying to find optimal set of strings for given string.**

> Given string: "FEEJEEDAI"

**Substrings values:**

> FE -   1
>   JE -  2
>   JEE - 3
>   AI -  4
>   DAI - 6

**Possible combinations:**

> 1) [FE-JE-DAI] - 1+2+6 = 9
>   2) [FE-JEE-DAI] - 1+3+6 = 10
>   3) [FE-JE-AI] - 1+3+4 = 8

**OPTIMAL COMBINATION - 2) [FE-JEE-DAI] scores 10**

I think it should go something like this:

1) check if string contain particular substring:

`var string = "FEEJEEDAI",
    substring = "JE";
  string.indexOf(substring) !== -1;`

2) If true find it's index

`var subStringIndex = string.indexOf(substring)`

3) Create new tempString to build  combination and 'cut off' `substring` from `string`

`var tempString =  string.slice(subStringIndex, substring.length)`

4) Iterate through `string` and find optimal `tempString`

I don't know how to build it into loop and and handle situation JE vs JEE, AI vs DAI

Comment: Can the same substring be found multiple times? Can two substrings overlap?

Comment: Yes substring can be found multiple times and yes they are overlapping each other - this is hardest part I guess.

Comment: So if you search the string "EEEEEE" for "EE" - 2 and "EEE" - 3 then what is the result?

Comment: All possible combinations so: EE-EE-EE, EEE-EEE, EE-EEE, EEE-EE now algorithm should choose best option depending on value added to substring

Comment: But what about overlaps? Can't it also be EE-EE-EE-EE-EE ?

Answer (score 8):

**Basically, you could use an iterative and recursive approach for getting all possible substrings of the string.**

This solution is splitted into 3 parts

1. Preparation
2. Collecting parts
3. Calculating score and create result set

---

#### Preparation

At start, all substrings of the string are collected in the `indices` object. The key is the index and the value is an object with a limit, which is the smallest length of the strings in the pattern array. The pattern array contains the index and the found substrings beginning at that index.

> `indices` object from the first example
>
> ```
> {
>     0: {
>         limit: 2,
>         pattern: [
>             {
>                 index: 0,
>                 string: "FE"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     3: {
>         limit: 2,
>         pattern: [
>             {
>                 index: 3,
>                 string: "JE"
>             },
>             {
>                 index: 3,
>                 string: "JEE"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     /* ... */
> }
> ```

#### Collecting parts

The main idea is to start at index zero with an empty array for collecting substrings.

To check, which parts are together in a group, you need to get the first substring at a given index or the next close one, then take the limit property, which is the length of the shortest substring, add the index and take it as the maximum index for searching group members.

> From the second example the first group consists of `'FE'`, `'EE'` and `'EEJ'`
>
> ```
> string      comment
> ----------  -------------------------------------
> 01 2345678  indices
> FE|EJEEDAI  
> FE|         matching pattern FE  at position 0
>  E|E        matching pattern EE  at position 1
>  E|EJ       matching pattern EEJ at position 1
> ^^          all starting substrings are in the same group
> ```

With that group, a new recursion is invoked, with an adjusted index and with the substring concatinated to the parts array.

#### Calculating score and create result set

If no more substring are found, the parts are joined and the score is calculated and pushed to the result set.

> Interpreting the result
>
> ```
>  [
>     {
>         parts: "0|FE|3|JE|6|DAI",
>         score: 9
>     },
>     /* ... */
> ]
> ```
>
> `parts` are a combination of indices and matching strings at the position
>
> ```
>  0|FE|3|JE|6|DAI
>  ^ ^^            at index 0 found FE
>       ^ ^^       at index 3 found JE
>            ^ ^^^ at index 6 found DAI
> ```
>
> `score` is calculated with the given weights of the substrings
>
> ```
> substring  weight
> ---------  ------
>  FE            1
>  JE            2
>  DAI           6
> ---------  ------
> score          9
> ```

The example three returns 11 unique combinations.

```js
function getParts(string, weights) {

    function collectParts(index, parts) {
        var group, limit;
        while (index < string.length && !indices[index]) {
            index++;
        }
        if (indices[index]) {
            group = indices[index].pattern;
            limit = index + indices[index].limit;
            while (++index < limit) {
                if (indices[index]) {
                    group = group.concat(indices[index].pattern);
                }
            }
            group.forEach(function (o) {
                collectParts(o.index + o.string.length, parts.concat(o.index, o.string));
            });
            return;
        }
        result.push({
            parts: parts.join('|'),
            score: parts.reduce(function (score, part) { return score + (weights[part] || 0); }, 0)
        });
    }

    var indices = {},
        pattern,
        result = [];

    Object.keys(weights).forEach(function (k) {
        var p = string.indexOf(k);
        while (p !== -1) {
            pattern = { index: p, string: k };
            if (indices[p]) {
                indices[p].pattern.push(pattern);
                if (indices[p].limit > k.length) {
                    indices[p].limit = k.length;
                }
            } else {
                indices[p] = { limit: k.length, pattern: [pattern] };
            }
            p = string.indexOf(k, p + 1);
        }
    });
    collectParts(0, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getParts("FEEJEEDAI", { FE: 1, JE: 2, JEE: 3, AI: 4, DAI: 6 }));
console.log(getParts("FEEJEEDAI", { FE: 1, JE: 2, JEE: 3, AI: 4, DAI: 6, EEJ: 5, EJE: 3, EE: 1 }));
console.log(getParts("EEEEEE", { EE: 2, EEE: 3 }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is the good solution. Maybe it would be an optimisation if during the preprocessing phase you would also record the smallest length per index, so you don't have to do that lookup during the recursive algorithm, which may get repeated during alternative branches in the recursion tree.

Comment: @trincot, great idea, now with limit for the smallest length pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you're slicing out the substring when you find them, since certain substrings are substrings of other substrings, search for the biggest ones first. For example, if you didn't find DAI, and you find AI, it can't be a part of DAI. You want to test for each substring, so you can put each substring into an array and loop through the array.